# Automatially add text to a div after an AJAX delete method with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to add an auto populated message to a results div to tell the user that their favorites list is empty after they delete the last one, but having no success.

The jQuery

```
$.getJSON("stuff/favorite").done(function(faves){
   ... // all the favorites list display stuff is here 

 // the delete function
 $('.remove_favorite').click(function(event){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
      $.ajax({
      url: "/stuff/favorite/"+id,
      method: "DELETE",
      data: id
    }).done(function(){
        $('div[data-id='+ id +']').fadeOut(function(){
          $(this).remove(); 
        });
    })
    if (faves == ""){ 
      $('#display-area').html("<div class='no-results'>Your list is empty!</div>");
    } // ends if
  }); // ends delete function
});  // ends .getJSON function
```

I've also tried moving the if faves == "" inside the .done function and after the remove function too with no luck.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Because of asynchrony

Comment: @charlietfl JSON data

Comment: Do not attach event handlers in other handlers unless you know what will happen!

Comment: Also `faves` has immutable state. After deleting `faves` still be unchanged

Comment: think the logic through,  `faves` can not be empty within the click handler or there wouldn't have been any data to create list in the first place

Comment: @charlietfl Isn't the the item effectively removed from favorites after the .done is called tho? Would it be empty at that point for the if statement to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got this to work, FWIW:

```
$.getJSON("stuff/favorite").done(function(faves){
   ... // all the favorites list display stuff is here 

 $('.remove_favorite').click(function(event){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
      $.ajax({
      url: "/stuff/favorite/"+id,
      method: "DELETE",
      data: id
    }).done(function(){
        $('div[data-id='+ id +']').fadeOut(function(){
          $(this).remove(); 
        });
    })

    // added a call to the JSON page here to test whether it had any items
    $.getJSON("stuff/favorite").done(function(faves){ 
      if (faves == ""){ 
        $('#display-area').html("<div class='no-results'>Your list is empty!</div>");
      }
    });

  }); // ends delete function
});  // ends .getJSON function
```

Answer (score 0):

Improve `done` logic:

```
.done(function(){

    // Add here excluding removed fave from `faves` list

    $('div[data-id='+ id +']').fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).remove();

      // And then add this to show message when faves is empty
      if (!faves.length){ 
        $('#display-area').html("<div class='no-results'>Your list is empty!</div>");
      }
    });
})
```

Provide to us `faves` arrays structure to make answers more suitable.

Comment: if `faves` is array it has to have length to be able to have created something to delete and create the ajax that has the `done` in your code

Comment: @charlietfl Not sure I understand what you mean by "and create the ajax that has the done in your code". Can you put that a different way, maybe?